# Mistake in simple XAML binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Why doesn't this binding update?

**code:**
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="usr" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=usr, Path=txt.Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication12.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBox Text="qwe" x:Name="txt" />
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TextBox inside the UserControl is inaccessible due to its protection level, also it is a field, you can never bind to those. You would need to expose it in the code behind of the UserControl as public property.

```
public TextBox Txt
{
    get { return txt; }
}
```

**Edit:** As Henk Holterman pointed out you might not want to expose the whole TextBox, so you could define a dependency property to which the TextBox internally binds for example.

Comment: Yep, that works. Don't understand why, it's marked as internal, should be visible.

Comment: And then expos a strng property, not a textbox.

Comment: @Poma: In bindings everything needs to be a public property, fields do not work.